# Set default value for a picklist filter in skuid page

Tags: picklist, skuid, skuid-model

#### Question

I've got a table of search results for a skuid page I'm building and have added a filter for a "type" picklist field. Everything is working just fine, but I'd like to be able to default the filter to a specific picklist value that section loads. Kind of like you can have other filters default to inactive or active initially. Is this possible? Are there any work arounds to achieve similar behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up this was pretty easy, albeit not exactly intuitive for the Skuid noob (me).

I followed the instructions for [table filters](http://help.skuidify.com/m/models-conditions-filters/l/102562-create-a-filterable-table) on skuid's doc site. With a couple modifications to the related condition on the model:

- Condition State: Filterable Default On
- Value: My Initial Value

When the page loads the filter starts in that state and works just like you're looking for.